# YII2 URL Configuration

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

How can I configure a url with parameter in YII2 as described below ?
I need to change this one

```
http://localhost/projectname/site/attraction?name=earth-cruise
```

to

```
http://localhost/projectname/earth-cruise
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom URL rule in your config, as described here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#named-parameters

Something similar to this should do it:

```
'<name:\w+>' => 'site/attraction'
```